# XML serialization issue in C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am working on a project where we are migrating from legacy code to new .net core code. Facing an issue during xml serialization.

This is what is being displayed in old application:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <Response xmlns="http://example.com/WebServices/">         
         <Type i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
         <UserId i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
      </Response>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

and in new code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <Response xmlns="http://example.com/WebServices/"> 
            <xsi:Type>PROCESSED</xsi:Type>
            <xsi:UserId />
        </Response>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

This is the class definition:

```
 [XmlType(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public class AResponse
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
            public ABody body { get; set; }
            [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
            public XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            public AResponse()
            {
                xmlns.Add("s", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
            }
        }
        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public class ABody
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "OAuthResponse", Namespace = "http://example.com/WebServices/")]
            public Response result { get; set; }
        }
        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "OAuthResponse", Namespace = "http://example.com/WebServices/")]
        public class Response
        {  
            [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", IsNullable = true)]
            public string Type { get; set; }
    
            
            [XmlElement(IsNullable = true, ElementName = "UserId", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
            public string UserId { get; set; } = "";       
        }
```

If you notice the difference between old and new xml being displayed, new code is automatically adding xsi tag and putting the namespace at header level and any change I make is not changing it. Can you please suggest how to make this work?

Comment: You explicitely said that `Type` and `UserId` should be in the `"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` namespace

Comment: Yes Klaus. I was expecting it to show in the same node like this:  <Type i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>  But instead. it created xsi tag and added namespace at the top in envelope. Is it possible to have it like I mentioned?

Comment: From an xml point of view it is completely irrelevant where the namespace declaration is located in the tree

Comment: Thank you Klaus. This is what I wanted to confirm. I will run few tests to see if it works the way it is and will mark your answer as done

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the "xsi:" in the Type and UserId elements, just remove `Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` from the XmlElementAtttribute, e.g.

```
[XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
public string Type { get; set; }

[XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
public string UserId { get; set; };
```

The `IsNullable = true` should remain, it makes `UserId = null` to be serialized as `<UserId xsi:nil="true" />`; `UserId = ""` will be serialized as `<UserId />`.